# Создание insert в php

Tags: php, insert

Добрый день. Я новичок, пытаюсь создать форму где можно вставлять данные в базу данных и отображать их на странице. У меня 2 таблицы в базе данных - film и category. Код следующий:

```
<?php // login page with php code
require_once 'log.php';
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $id = get_post($conn, 'id');
    $query = "DELETE FROM film WHERE id='$id'";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    if (!$result)
        echo "DELETE failed: $query<br>" .
        $conn->error . "<br><br>";
}
if (isset($_POST['title']) &&
        isset($_POST['director']) &&
        isset($_POST['year']) &&
        isset($_POST['type'])) {
    $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
    $director = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['director']);
    $year = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['year']);
    $type = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['type']);
    $query1 = "INSERT INTO film (title, director, year) VALUES ($title', '$director', '$year')";
    $query2 = "INSERT INTO category (type) VALUES ('$type')";
    $result1 = $conn->query($query1);
    $result2 = $conn->query($query2);
    if (!$result1)
        echo "INSERT failed: $query1<br>" .
        $conn->error . "<br><br>";
    if (!$result2)
        echo "INSERT failed: $query2<br>" .
        $conn->error . "<br><br>";
}
echo <<<_END
    <form action="" method="post"><pre>
    Title <input type="text" name="title">
    Director <input type="text" name="director">
    Year <input type="text" name="year">
    Type <input type="text" name="type">
    <input type="submit" value="ADD RECORD">
    </pre></form>
    _END;
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr> <th>Title</th> <th>Director</th> <th>Year</th> <th>Genre</th> <th>Update</th> <th>Delete</th></tr>";
    $query = "SELECT title,director,year,type FROM film JOIN category ON category.catID=film.catID";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . $conn->error);  
    $rows = $result->num_rows;
    for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
    {
    $result->data_seek($j);
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

                echo "<tr>";
                echo '<td>' . $row[0] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row[1] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row[2] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row[3] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>Edit</td>';
                echo '<td><button type="delete" name="delete" value="delete">delete</button></td>';
                echo "</tr>"; 
        } 
        echo "</table>";

?>
```

Выдает ошибку

> "INSERT failed: INSERT INTO film (title, director, year) VALUES ('h', 'h', '1890')"

Что не так?

**Обновление**

```
<?php // login page with php code
require_once 'log.php';

if (isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['id']))
{
$id = get_post($conn, 'id');
$query = "DELETE FROM film WHERE id='$id'";
$result = $conn->query($query);
if (!$result) echo "DELETE failed: $query<br>" .
$conn->error . "<br><br>";
}

if (isset($_POST['title']) &&
isset($_POST['director']) &&
isset($_POST['year']) &&
isset($_POST['type']))  
{

$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
$director = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['director']);
$year = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['year']);
$type = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['type']);
$query = "INSERT INTO film (title, director, year, type) VALUES ('".$title."', '".$director."', '".$year."', '".$type."')";
$result = $conn->query($query);
if (!$result) echo "INSERT failed: $query<br>" .
$conn->error . "<br><br>";
}
echo <<<_END
<form action="" method="post"><pre>
Title <input type="text" name="title">
Director <input type="text" name="director">
Year <input type="text" name="year">
<input type="radio" name="type" id="drama" value="drama" checked> drama<br>
<input type="radio" name="type" id="mystery" value="mystery"> mystery<br>
<input type="radio" name="type" id="thriller" value="thriller"> thriller <br>
<input type="radio" name="type" id="comedy" value="comedy">  comedy
<input type="submit" value="ADD RECORD">
</pre></form>
_END;
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr> <th>ID</th>  <th>Title</th> <th>Director</th> <th>Year</th><th>Category</th><th>Update</th> <th>Delete</th></tr>";
$query = "SELECT id,title,director,year,type FROM film";
$result = $conn->query($query);
if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . $conn->error);  
$rows = $result->num_rows;
for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
{
$result->data_seek($j);
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row[0] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row[1] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row[2] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row[3] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row[4] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>Edit</td>';
    echo '<td><form action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="delete" value="yes">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="$row[id]">
<input type="submit" value="delete"></form></td>'; 
    echo '</tr>';
} 
echo "</table>";
$result->close();
$conn->close();
function get_post($conn, $var)
{
return $conn->real_escape_string($_POST[$var]);
}
?>
```

Это переделанная версия. Убрала вторую таблицу из базы данных, заполнение формы работает, а удаление нет. В чем ошибка?

Comment: Готовый рабочий пример, без всего того ужаса, что насоветовали ниже, phpfaq.ru/safemysql/crud

Comment: @Ипатьев Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: @Nic я нигде не видел подобного правила, относящегося к комментариям. Уж про развернутые-то ответы никто не может меня упрекнуть в том, что я их не пишу. Если я вижу, что вопрос стоит того. Для вопроса-оффтопика же, вида "я тут накатал 5 экранов кода, найдите мне в нем ошибку" я слишком ценю свое время, поскольку никакой ответ на него не "добавит  знаний в Рунет".

Comment: @Ипатьев Пожалуйста, проголосуйте за закрытие, в таком случае.

Answer (score 1):

В sql-запросы нужно правильно вписать переменные. Например, так.

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO film (title, director, year) VALUES ('".$title."', '".$director."', ".$year.")";
$query2 = "INSERT INTO category (type) VALUES ('".$type."')";
```

На всякий случай, проверьте, соответствуют ли типы данных (переменной и поля таблицы) для `title`, `director`, `year` и `type`.

PS: Для лучшей читаемости, PHP-переменные можно вставлять в запрос так:

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO film (title, director, year) VALUES ('{$title}', '{$director}', '{$year}')";
$query2 = "INSERT INTO category (type) VALUES ('{$type}')";
```

Comment: Да, самый лучший вариант ('{$param}')

Comment: Спрашивать, что не так со "вписыванием переменных" в исходном вопросе, видимо, бесполезно.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php